# How to communicate with external CLIs with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, command

When interacting with clis, for example, taking `npm init`, we can run the command and get the output by the following code

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');
exec('npm init', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err)
  } else {
   console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
   console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
  }
});
```

But we cannot pass the project name, version name etc.. How to achieve this. Pls answer with the example of `npm init` command

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Write to the child process stdin.

Comment: Pls help me with that, i'm new to nodejs

Answer (score 0):

Use the stdin channel each process provides. For that, use the node [`child_process.spawn`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_processspawncommand-args-options) method instead:

```js
const { spawn } = require('child_process');


const npm = spawn('npm', ["init"]);

npm.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
npm.stderr.pipe(process.stderr);

npm.on("exit", () => {

    console.log("npm exited");
    process.exit();

});


const answers = [
    "my-awesome-cli",        // package name
    "0.0.1",                 // version number
    "desciprtion",           // description
    "index.js",              // entry point
    "",                      // test command
    "",                      // git reposiroty
    "",                      // keywords
    "Marc Stirner",          // author
    "MIT"                    // license
];


setInterval(() => {
    if (answers.length > 0) {

        // get first item from array
        let answer = answers.shift();

        // print value we pass to npm
        console.log("Write to npm child:", answer);

        // write chunk to stdin
        npm.stdin.write(`${answer}\r\n`);

    } else {

        //npm.stdin.end();
        console.log("Hit final enter")
        npm.stdin.write(`\r\n`);

    }
}, 800);
```

My example spwans the npm command, use the stdin channel to write the answer to the process, and pipe the stdout&stderr output from the npm command to the node.js process.

You can do this with `exec` too, since it returns as well a [`child_process`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/child_process.html#class-childprocess) object.

Read more on the node.js docs, they are very well documented.